# Devstack cannot ssh into VM when using Heat

Tags: devstack, openstack-heat

I am using devstack on my Mac. When launching an instance via the console, I can ssh into the new instance using the appropriate key. However, if I launch an instance using a Heat stack-create, defining the same key pair and the same image and all that, I cannot ssh into the VM.

Does anyone have an idea why that may be happening? I keep getting "Permission denied (publickey).", which indicates that the key was apparently not injected into the new VM, but as I said, this only breaks if I use Heat.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I found that for Heat-deployed instances, I need to log in as ec2-user. I was using 'ubuntu' as the login user, which is what works for manually launched instances (for my Ubuntu image, of course).